# Symfony Nelmio Solarium Bundle FilterQuery

Tags: php, symfony, solr, solarium

When I execute this code in solr API

```
....fq=title:(bionformatics OR scince)...
```

It works fine and return data that fit to Filter Query.

But when I try the same query in Solarium bundle

```
$client = $this->solr->getClient();
$query = $client->createSelect();
$query->setFilterQueries('title:("bionformatics" OR "scince")');
```

I get this error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Solarium\QueryType\Select\Query\Query::addFilterQueries() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in
>   /var/www/html/conference/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/QueryType/Select/Query/Query.php
>   on line 737 and defined

I must notice that Solarium bundle works well with

**`$query->setQuery('title:"bionformatics" OR title:"scince"');`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

try:

```
$query->setFilterQueries(array('titleFilter' => 'title:("bioinformatics" OR "science")'));
```

Or since you only want to add a single Filterquery use the documented way from the solarium docs (http://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/select-query/building-a-select-query/adding-filterqueries/)

```
// get a select query instance
$query = $client->createSelect();

// create a filterquery
$query->createFilterQuery('maxprice')->setQuery('price:[1 TO 300]');

// this executes the query and returns the result
$resultset = $client->select($query);
```

When you look at this example it is also clear why setFilterQueries uses the array syntax, since every filterquery needs its unique identifier.